# Alamofire breaks other pods

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire

When I add alamofire to my Podfile it breaks all the others.  I think it's because of the frameworks thing?  Basically where I used to have this in my bridging header:

```
#import <AFNetworking.h>
```

now it says it can't find AFNetworking.h

Does that for all of the headers that I get via Pods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>`, it seems to be working for me

Comment: That works for AFNetworking, but the others are failing.  For example, I use the UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK pod, and if I import <UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK/UAirship.h> it says not found, even though I see that in Pods/Headers/Public

Comment: OK, it looks like it's just that one, and it doesn't seem to like the dashes.

Comment: It's an issue with that library.  I changed it to underscores and now it tries to import, but I'm getting "include of non-modular header inside framework module' with it.  It set that to be allowed in the project but it's still failing

Comment: I just tried installing the latest UrbanAirship library and it seems that they've removed `UAirship.h` and replaced it with `AirshipLib.h`. Doing `#import <UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK/AirshipLib.h>` seems to compile successfully.

Comment: Are you able to do an import in a swift file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76922/discussion-between-gargoyle-and-sean).